Count Avg of last 36 months when months are in a wide format(cant change this format)
I have a weird snowflake table format which is causing issues when showing last 36 months of data only.
in words, i want to see last 36 months of data so when looking at current date, everything before May 2021 should show as 0.
The fiscal year starts from Oct hence the table months are shifted.
The years go further than 2021 but i only want last 36 months.
the platform is snowflake script but if you have a sql script i can translate to snowflake as well.
any advice would be appreciated.
Original Table im starting with:



Account
Year
Oct
Nov
Dec
Jan
Feb
Mar
Apr
May
Jun
Jul
Aug
Sep




A1
2021
1
2
3
4
5
6
44
55
66
77
88
99


A2
2022
1
2
3
4
5
6
44
55
66
77
88
99


A3
2023
1
2
3
4
5
6
44
55
66
77
88
99


A4
2024
1
2
3
4
5
6









The result table im struggling to get:



Account
Year
Oct
Nov
Dec
Jan
Feb
Mar
Apr
May
Jun
Jul
Aug
Sep




A1
2021
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
55
66
77
88
99


A2
2022
1
2
3
4
5
6
44
55
66
77
88
99


A3
2023
1
2
3
4
5
6
44
55
66
77
88
99


A4
2024
1
2
3
4
5
6
7









Rather than carry around this complexity, I would "unpack" this table by creating a view that has columns account, year, month_number, month_name that is a 12-way self join. once you have that, the rest is easy.

This could be done, by UNPIVOT then two filters and a rePIVOT,
OR given the columns are known and fixed at 12:
with cte_pretending_to_be_a_table(Account,Year,Oct,Nov,Dec,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep) as (
    select * from values
    ('A-1', 2019, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99),
    ('A0', 2020, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99),
    ('A1', 2021, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99),
    ('A2', 2022, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99),
    ('A3', 2023, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99),
    ('A4', 2024, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, null, null, null, null, null, null)
)
select 
    d.account, 
    d.year,
    date_trunc('month', dateadd('year',-3, current_date())) as m3y,
    iff(date_from_parts(d.year-1, 10, 1) >= m3y, oct, 0) as oct,
    iff(date_from_parts(d.year-1, 11, 1) >= m3y, nov, 0) as nov,
    iff(date_from_parts(d.year-1, 12, 1) >= m3y, dec, 0) as dec,
    iff(date_from_parts(d.year, 1, 1) >= m3y, jan, 0) as jan,
    /* ... */
    iff(date_from_parts(d.year, 5, 1) >= m3y, may, 0) as may,
    iff(date_from_parts(d.year, 6, 1) >= m3y, jun, 0) as jun,
    /* ... */
from cte_pretending_to_be_a_table as d
where year(current_date())-3 <= d.year
order by d.year
;




ACCOUNT
YEAR
M3Y
OCT
NOV
DEC
JAN
MAY
JUN




A1
2021
2021-05-01
0
0
0
0
55
66


A2
2022
2021-05-01
1
2
3
4
55
66


A3
2023
2021-05-01
1
2
3
4
55
66


A4
2024
2021-05-01
1
2
3
4






Hi, While it produces the right answer, can you please add some comments as to where the Unpivot, filters and repivot is happening?

none of those bits are happening... thus the OR

will you still put "d.year-1" if the year column was already in fiscal year format?

if you already have a column that is the aggregate you wish to work in, aka fiscal year, then I would use that over generating it. Except when to get the column requires a JOIN and the JOIN is only done for this aggregation, at which point I would be more inclined to generate the aggregation value, as my belief this is faster. As long as if you are doing a filter on this aggregation column, then filtering in pre-aggregate value space should also be used, to avoid loading too many rows, which get thrown away.
